# Does The Law of Large Numbers Apply to All Events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

My school has a research program and I potentially want to use this topic but I'm unsure if it can be answered with a simple response or if the question merits any research for that matter.

I want to try and figure out if the law of large numbers applies to events with individual/mutually exclusive outcomes.  The law states as sample size grows, the mean tends to get closer to the average expected value, but does this same concept apply to events with independent outcomes such as fair coin tosses. Theoretically, I can toss a fair coin 100 times and get 100 heads. However seemingly improbable, still possible. I coin could be flipped ∞ times and get ∞ heads. This seemingly contradicts the Law of Large numbers. This is the topic I want to dive into. However, still being fairly new to probability, I'm unsure of the depth required or if this is even a question that merits research.

Feedback is appreciated.

*Undergrad

Edit: My question has been answered. There is no need for any new responses. However, if you want to, feel free.

Comment: "*A coin could be flipped $\infty$ times and get $\infty$ heads (and zero tails).*"  Do not conflate an event as being *feasible* with the event as occurring with positive probability.  Further, do not mistake an event as being feasible as having much of anything to do with the *mean* as being what it is.  Read more carefully what the Law of Large Numbers says.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia entry on this?

Comment: @JMoravitz I'll look more into it. Thank you for your response. However, in my initial statement, I don't associate a positive probability with 100 consecutive coin flips. The odds this occurring are highly improbable. If you don't mind, can you please elaborate on your initial statement and point out further flaws with my argument.

Comment: @user619894 I've read the Wikipedia entry. Is there something that I'm missing? Please feel free to point out any potential flaws with my argument.

Comment: If you did a large number of trials with 500 people in say the US surveyed in each trial and asked them their net worth, you might arrive at a number that is tending closer to the population mean net worth of US. However, if you do the same trial each year at a TED conference surveying the attendees, those trials might not tend towards the mean due to the presence of a  large number of 'outliers' (say Bill Gates, Jeff Bezos et al.,). Applying Law of Large numbers requires total randomness. Check out some interesting books by Nasim Nicholas Taleb - *Fooled by Randomness* and *Black Swan*.

Comment: @vvgiri Okay bear with me hear. So I completely understand your analogy. If you surveyed 500 random people across the U.S with the only commonality being the fact that they are American, you may reach some mean that gives you a likelihood of the average NW in the U.S. But, doing this at a TedTalk invalidates your findings because their is a bias in your sampling. I completely get that analogy. However, how does this relate to my topic proposal? There is no bias in my testing. I am testing events with independent outcomes to see if the Law is all encompassing. I would appretiate your response.

Comment: Perhaps it may help to talk not about "*the average proportion of heads vs tails in a specific result of flips which have already occurred*" and instead talk about "*the expected average proportion of heads vs tails in a sequence of flips which have not yet occurred.*"  Sure, the proportion of heads vs tails in your hypothetical sequence of flips all resulting in heads is far and away skewed towards heads, however when considering all possible sequences of flips they will overwhelmingly tend towards having a nearly even amount of heads and tails.

Comment: It again sounds as though you are looking at a very specific scenario which almost never occurs and are looking at proportions there and comparing this to the general scenario.  There is no contradiction here, merely a misunderstanding on your part about what the law of large numbers actually says.  That the overwhelming majority of possible sequences of flips will be such that there is a nearly even number of heads and tails does not in and of itself say that a sequence with all heads is "infeasible/impossible", merely that it is *highly* unlikely.

Comment: @JMoravitz "instead talk about "the expected average proportion of heads vs tails in a sequence of flips which have not yet occurred.""  I  guess this is the statement I was looking for. One that completely invalidates my argument. You are right. In my theoretical scenario, I'm too fixated on what can happen and not what will likely happen.

Comment: @JMoravitz I appretiate you taking the time to respond. Not an obligation by any means, but do you have any recommendations on probability topics I could I pursue for undergraduate research?